# How do vehicles become disabled?

Tags: battlefield-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens when a vehicle is “disabled” in Battlefield 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35099/what-happens-when-a-vehicle-is-disabled-in-battlefield-3)

I noticed sometimes that when I hit a vehicle it becomes disabled.  I'm not sure if it has something to do with the HP they have left or where I hit the vehicle.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

Vehicles become disabled once they drop low enough in health. I believe its in the range of 25% to 50% health.

From the [help site of EA:](https://help.ea.com/article/bf3-gameplay-and-items)

> **How do vehicles regenerate in Battlefield 3?**
>   Vehicles will regenerate up to 25% of hit points as long as they are not "disabled", but will require an Engineer to complete the repair in order to be useable.  A vehicle becomes disabled after taking a certain amount of damage (different for each vehicle).  Aircraft, for example, become disabled at 50% health.  The vehicle continues to be "disabled" until it’s repaired to 100% hit points.